# joining on a table that references another table's column twice

Tags: mysql, postgresql, join

I have this table `Meeting` in **POSTGRESQL** that looks like:

```
id | subject  | time                |
1  | Eat stuff| 2017-08-23 00:00:00 |
2  | Do stuff | 2017-08-28 00:00:00 |
```

And another table `SimilarMeeting` that looks like:

```
meetingId | similarId | score |
1         | 2         | 0.8   |
```

where `SimilarMeeting.meetingId` and `SimilarMeeting.similarId` are foreign keys to the `Meeting` table. I'm trying to generate a join statement that'd give me a result that looks like:

```
meetingSubject | similarSubject | score
Eat stuff      | Do stuff       | 0.8
```

I'm kinda stumped here as two inner joins don't work here since the first inner join and second inner join reference two different `Meeting` rows.

```
select "ma"."subject", "mb"."subject",     
"eva"."SimilarMeeting"."similarityScore" from "eva"."SimilarMeeting" 
join "eva"."Meeting" AS ma on "eva"."SimilarMeeting"."meetingId" = "ma"."id"
join "eva"."Meeting" AS mb on "eva"."SimilarMeeting"."similarId" = "ma"."id"
```

Answer (score 1):

in the last line, in the join condition, you join with ma instead of mb.